# Using "Method" MethodInfo property from an Action<T> delegate in il.EmitCall

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit

Is something like this possible?

```
//
//  create a delegate
Action<Type> action = (t) => t.DoSomething;

//
// get the IL generator for a method
ILGenerator il = myMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

//
// try and call the delegate
il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, action.Method, null);
```

Im getting a MethodAccessException whenever I try to invoke the method.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Im getting a MethodAccessException whenever I try to invoke the method.

This is because the method generated for the C# `(t) => t.DoSomething` lambda is private. Chances are this lambda won't be static, either, depending on which of the local variables it captures from the outer method. You're issuing a `callvirt` instruction but you don't appear to be supplying an instance.

You can verify this by loading your application's code in Reflector and looking at the implementation of your `(t) => t.DoSomething` lambda.

You need to either:

- Upgrade your lambda to a real `public static` method in an externally-visible class
- Find a way to include a parameter of type `Action<Type>` in your IL method, generate code that calls `Action<Type>.Invoke`, then pass your `action` variable into the generated method

Comment: I can see the MethodInfo IsPrivate is true, is there a way to change this?  Otherwise I can just use a Public static member, but its neater with a Lambda :)

Thanks

Comment: There's no way to change this; it's an implementation detail of the C# compiler

Comment: Thinking about this further, your better option might be to find a way to pass the `action` delegate into your generated method, either by adding a parameter, or by making your generated method an class instance member and setting a field on that class. Because you'd be calling your lambda through a delegate, you won't be sensitive to how that lambda is implemented.

Comment: Yea, that seems to be a solution, thanks!  I would vote this up, but cant! doh

Answer (score 0):

See if this is related to what is mention [Here](http://www.byteblocks.com/post/2010/05/25/MethodAccessException-Upgrading-Assemblies-to-Net40.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you use a dynamic method you can use the skip visibility checks in the jitter.